# Is there a way to open tabs in the background? I don't want new tabs grabbing focus

Tags: keyboard, finder, tabs

I often like to open several folders in new tabs, but keep the focus on the parent folder I'm selecting from. My ADHD brain gets distracted by the OS auto-switching the focus to the latest new tab This constantly breaks my train of thought because the system keeps wiping away the list I am concentrating on.

Are there any modifier keys or right-click options to open new tab in background?

Comment: If it's not possible, why not use the disclosure arrows, or Column View instead?

Comment: I don't understand, I've been using this site for about a decade. I've never gotten an answer to my question. It's always down-voted but it's never explained why. It's nitpicked to death with this very hyper-rigid community. You can't comment here. Start a new question. It seems to be built 100% for engineers but it drives me insane.

Comment: FWIW, your question is a little clunky to read — at least it is for me. As an aside, I think the site is built for everyone but moderated by anal-retentives and frequented by at least an adequately-sized crew of people who get a rush from downvoting. Downvotes are justified because it's for your own good. They don't leave comments because they live in abject terror of being downvoted themselves and fear that you will pursue and downvote them in perpetuity, and are unnecessary anyway since the reason is in the site documentation somewhere. Just my observations.

Comment: Thanks @Mockman, I rewrote it. I also thank you for your impressions of how anal-retentive many mods are, and the culture of people just loving to downvote stuff just because they can, vs trying to help. That is very sad but I've seen this inclination for past 25 years. These are human deficits that should have been AI'd away long ago.

Comment: Veering a little off-topic here but it feels like every day I see a new user's first question downvoted (and sometimes closed) but without any reason provided. I believe that this behaviour just chases potential new users away permanently. I don't expect anything to change but I'd like to see restrictions on downvoting sub-100 rep users without commenting usefully.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that and I'm sure others will too.  It's the antithesis of help to crap on people just because of reputation points. It's OK for me if no one has suggested solution re macro apps etc. But for Christ's sake, what is the Mission of StackExchange? To be an elite gated community of tech gods slapping down the unworthy or a democratized system for crowdsourcing answers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have exactly what you want (without purchasing some tool with that capability), however, if your Finder preference for 'open folders in tabs instead of new windows' is checked, then you can open selected folders in new tabs with command-option-o. At least, you can in Sierra.

Note that it won't happen in the background as the last item selected will become the active tab in the window. However, your original selection will be maintained in the initial tab.

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with CMD-OPT-o, and I imagine you're right that the capability is just not there the way it's there in browser tab management.  I don't know how to use scripting, or macros. But if anyone has a recommended macro app that could [open new tab] [select previous tab], maybe that would achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: As I understand it, Apple introduced finder tabs in 10.9, but never implemented it into applescript. Unfortunately, they also didn't make the contextual menu item a full menu item so you cannot casually assign a keyboard shortcut. Maybe take a look at [Keyboard Maestro](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/open-folder-in-a-new-tab/9925), which seems a pretty flexible tool. Some of its eager and zealous users may be able to suggest practical ideas.

Comment: Many thanks, I've heard of it, and i will try it.